# Using webmock to mock XMLRPC client in rspec-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, xml-rpc, webmock

I'm trying to spec a client that goes through the following series of calls via XMLRPC:

```
post (https) myservice.auth.login (with params login, password)
post (http) myservice.items.list (with sessionid from login)
```

I'm trying to mock these so I don't have to hit a production XMLRPC service, so I did this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe ItemList do
  it "hydrates the model" do
    stub_request(:post, 'secure-api.myservice.com/webservices/xmlrpc/').
      with(:body =~ /myservice.auth.login/m).
      to_return(:body => AUTH_XML, :status => 200).
    stub_request(:post, 'api.myservice.com/webservices/xmlrpc/').
      with(:body =~ /myservice.items.list/m).
      to_return(:body => ITEMLIST_XML, :status => 200)

    expect{ItemList.hydrate_item_list}.to change(ItemList, :count).from(0).to(3)
  end
end

ITEMLIST_XML=<<EOD
<myserviceResponse sessionid="000123401200002312" membername="abc">
   <itemList>
      <item itemid="123" name="Faves" public="false" membername="abc" itemcount="30" views="20">
         <description>Stuff I like</description>
         <keywords>walks, rain, pina colada</keywords>
    </item>
      <item itemid="124" name="Yuck!" public="false" membername="abc" itemcount="35" views="5">
         <description>Stuff I don't like</description>
         <keywords>spinach, brussle sprouts, liver</keywords>
      </item>
      <item itemid="125" name="Project" public="true" membername="def" itemcount="5" views="2">
         <description>Brochure images</description>
         <keywords></keywords>
      </item>
   </itemList>
</myserviceResponse>
EOD

AUTH_XML=<<EOD
<myserviceResponse sessionID="10301">
   <memberName>redrover</memberName>
</myserviceResponse>
EOD
```

Basically, I don't care what is passed into `auth` for this spec. I want to authorize anyhow because it's the hoop I need to jump before actually hydrating the model.

These stubs don't seem to be intercepting the posts and I don't understand how I might go about debugging it.

Any hints appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: which http library are you using?

Comment: XMLRPC::Client (the Ruby std lib version), which presumably uses Net::HTTP.